# Primefaces <p:selectOneMenu> display issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a full page layout. Top layoutUnit is having a menu and selectOneMenu. The menu items are not getting displayed properly. The menu items are overlapping with selectOneMenus.

[image]

here is my xhtml code and styles used.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

    <style type="text/css">
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

**.ui-layout-north {
    z-index: 20 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}**

</style>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:layout fullPage="true" id="layout1">

        <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" size="104">
            <h:form>
<p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true" id="menubar1">
</p:menubar>
<h:panelGroup id="t1">
                    <p:toolbar rendered="#{menuBean.renderP1}" id="toolbar1">
                        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
<p:selectOneMenu id="prod" value="#{menuBean.product}"
                                style="width:155px;" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Select a product">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select product" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{menuBean.products}" />
                                <!-- Product changed -->
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="prodVar,brkType,brkRevision"
                                    listener="#{menuBean.productChanged}" />

                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:spacer width="50" height="10" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="prodVar" value="#{menuBean.productVariant}"
                                style="width:165px;" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Select product variant">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Variant" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{menuBean.productVariants}" />
                                <!-- productVariant changed -->
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="brkType,brkRevision"
                                    listener="#{menuBean.productVariantChanged}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:toolbarGroup>
                    </p:toolbar>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
            <h:form id="form2">
                <h:panelGroup id="t2">
                    <p:tabView id="tabView" rendered="#{menuBean.renderP2}">

                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:tab>

                    </p:tabView>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: what's your primefaces version ?

Answer (score 0):

i remember that it is reported to Cagatay sometime ago here is the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2956) and fixed with the version of primefaces 3.0RC1. Also, you can try adding to your css file to make layouts visible.

```
.ui-layout-north {
    overflow:visible !important;
}

.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution to fix this display issue. For a work around I had moved all the select menus from north to center layout. It fixed the issue temporarily.